# list files in subfolders and put in array as key = value

Tags: php, arrays, filesystems

I am sorry if this question is obvious for the ninjas, but I am quite a novice in PHP and I am struggling with it all day ..

I am trying to get a list of all files from a folder structure.

Currently it gives me something like

Array([0]->path/filename [1]->path/filename) Array([0]->path/filename [1]->path/filename..)

(one for each folder)

```
function o99_list_all_files_in_dir($dir) //need to ocheck for server compatibility (unix,linux,win)
{ 

    $root = scandir($dir); 
    foreach($root as $value) 
    { 
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;} 

        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result[]="$dir/$value";continue;} 

    //if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result["$dir"]="$value";continue;} 

        foreach(k99_list_all_files_in_dir("$dir/$value") as $value) 
        { 
            $result[]=$value; 

        //$result["$dir"]=$value; 
        }
    } 

    //print_r($result);
    return $result; 
}
```

Few questions :

1 - I need both the path and the filename pair so I thought to get an array like so :

results([path] -> [filename] [anotherpath] -> [anotherfilename]).

but if I try to construct another array (switch uncomment and comment lines) the function will give me only the 1st file in each dir.

2 - Later on , I am using this function in order to have both the path and filename seperated , So I tried this  :

```
$result = o99_list_all_files_in_dir($upload_dir);   
                foreach ($result as $image) {
                 reset($image);
                 while (list($key, $val) = each($image)) {
                    // echo "$key => $val\n";
                 }
                $filename = pathinfo($image);// I need the path here ...
                         ...
```

... but obviously it is not working (otherwise I would not be here :-)

3 - Bonus question : How can I filter files from the results (like thumbs.db for example) or decide how to ignore or not certain extensions ??

**EDIT I**
4 - !important (forgot before) - what do I need to be careful about when dealing with unknows server paths (Linux, Win, Unix) ...will this function work on all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function scanFileNameRecursivly($path = '', &$name = array() )
{
  $path = $path == ''? dirname(__FILE__) : $path;
  $lists = @scandir($path);

  if(!empty($lists))
  {
      foreach($lists as $f)
      { 
          if(is_dir($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$f) && $f != ".." && $f != ".")
          {
              scanFileNameRecursivly($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$f, &$name); 
          }
          else
          {
              $name[] = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$f;
          }
      }
  }
  return $name;
}

$path = "abs path to your directory";
$file_names = scanFileNameRecursivly($path);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($file_names);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but this is giving only a simple array like I had before (or maybe I am using it wrong..)